# Como obter os dados de um arquivo dentro bucket com Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-aws

Gostaria de obter os dados de um arquivo que está dentro do Bucket da AWS utilizando o Node.JS como por exemplo URL do arquivo, mas estou tendo alguns erros

Estou com seguinte código:

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
    
aws.config.update({
 accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
 secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET,
});
  
const s3 = new aws.S3()

const getS3Object = async objectKey => {
    console.log('bucket', S3_BUCKET);
    try {
        const params = {
          Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
          Key: objectKey 
        }
    
        const data = await s3.getObjectAttributes(params).promise();
        console.log(data);
                         
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`Could not retrieve file from S3: ${e.message}`)
      }
}

export default getS3Object
```

Mas ai estou tendo o seguinte problema

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cabrito\.aws\config'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:95:26)
    at IniLoader.parseFile (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\shared-ini\ini-loader.js:6:47)
    at IniLoader.loadFrom (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\shared-ini\ini-loader.js:56:30)
    at getRegion (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\node_loader.js:118:32)
    at Config.region (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\node_loader.js:173:18)
    at Config.set (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:524:39)
    at Config.<anonymous> (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:359:12)
    at Config.each (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:512:32)
    at new Config (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:358:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\node_loader.js:188:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module._compile (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:136:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (PC\Documents\projeto\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:141:7) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\cabrito\\.aws\\config'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tendo um erro pra acessar o arquivo config.
Ao invés de usar o "aws.config.update", tente utilizar a instância do objeto do S3 para passar os dados de conexão com o Bucket:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET
});
```